# Vue.js warning Invalid prop: type check failed for prop "xxxx" Expected Object, got String

Tags: vue.js

Even if this prop got a warning , it's running fine ... but WHY this warning on prop locale ?

```
  [Vue warn]: Invalid prop: type check failed for prop "locale". Expected Object, got String.

  <PayPal v-show="displayPaypalButtons" :buttonStyle="bStyle" locale="fr_FR" :client="credentials" amount="50.00" currency="EUR" env="sandbox" :invoice-number="invoiceNumber"></PayPal>
```

Comment: Could you add the used library?

Comment: That's strange - just had look at the https://github.com/khoanguyen96/vue-paypal-checkout source, and locale is expected to be String.
Am I right that you are using this package ?

Comment: yes I am...  it's running fine , but the warning message is always displayed....

Answer (score -1):

Please use: `locale="fr_FR" OR v-bind:locale="fr_FR"`.

Comment: Can you explain further how to solve the problem? The code already contains that `locale` attribute